# Why does getAttribute not exist on type "Node"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, deno

I'm converting some Javascript I wrote into a Deno TypeScript module. The script uses deno-dom to get all the "a[href]" links off of a page, and returns a list of links. The script is working correctly, however, when I test the code using `deno test`, it complains

`"TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'Node'"`

My understanding is that the Element type is a "type" of the Node type - but my attempts at intelligently declaring this has failed. What am I misunderstanding here?

Here's the full function in question:

```js
import { DOMParser } from "https://deno.land/x/deno_dom/deno-dom-wasm.ts";

export async function getAllLinks(
  url: string,
  slice = 5,
): Promise<{ source: string; links: string[] }> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const content: string = await response.text();

    // Parse the HTML content using JSDOM
    const document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");

    if (document === null) throw new Error("Failed to parse HTML");
    const baseUrl = response.url;

    // Find all links on the page
    const linkSelector = document.querySelectorAll(
      'a[href^="http:"], a[href^="https:"]',
    );

    if (linkSelector === undefined || linkSelector === null){
      throw new Error("No links found");
    }
    const links = Array.from(linkSelector, (link: Element) => link.getAttribute("href"))
      .map((link: string) => {
        // Convert relative links to absolute URLs
        const absoluteURL = new URL(link, baseUrl);
        return absoluteURL.href;
      })
      .filter((link: string) => {
        // Filter out links that are on the same domain as the URL
        const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
        const parsedLink = new URL(link);
        return parsedUrl.hostname !== parsedLink.hostname;
      });

    return {
      source: baseUrl,
      links: links.slice(0, slice),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Declaring the `(link)` as `(link: Element)` causes the prior `linkSelector`  before it in the `Array.from` to complain of this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable<Element> | ArrayLike<Element>, mapfn: (v: Element, k: number) => string | null, thisArg?: any): (string | null)[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'NodeList' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<Element> | ArrayLike<Element>'.
      Type 'NodeList' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<Element>'.
        'number' index signatures are incompatible.
          Type 'Node' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 127 more.  Overload 2 of 4, '(arrayLike: ArrayLike<Element>, mapfn: (v: Element, k: number) => string | null, thisArg?: any): (string | null)[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'NodeList' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<Element>'.deno-ts(2769)
```

And also breaks the next lines `(link: string)` declaration with this complaint:

```
argument of type '(link: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string | null, index: number, array: (string | null)[]) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'link' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.deno-ts(2345)
```

What makes this all the more confusing is that the code still executes completely fine no matter my chosen type declarations.

Comment: A [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) doesn't have a `getAttribute` method. An [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) has a `getAttribute` method. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. `(link: Element) => link.getAttribute("href")` should solve your problem.

Comment: This actually looks weird as TS builtin's `querySelectorAll` (not in deno) returns `NodeListOf<Element>`(https://tsplay.dev/W47b7m) and I'd expect `deno-dom` to be same

Comment: Actually in vanilla TS you would use `Array.from( document.querySelectorAll<HTMLAnchorElement>('a[href]') ,a=>a.href)` to use `<a>` and simply get full URL (attribute can be relative or whatever)

Comment: Elements (which have attributes) are types of node, but so are text nodes, comment nodes, etc.

Comment: This is an outstanding issue. See [b-fuze/deno-dom#4 (comment)](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/4#issuecomment-716299531). And for the `"href"` property on anchors specifically, see [b-fuze/deno-dom#72 (comment)](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/72#issuecomment-1250615385)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76615793/why-does-getattribute-not-exist-on-type-node#comment135089446_76615793) If those comments address your question, I can compose an answer from them. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: jsejcksn - Your comment in particular solves this question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an outstanding issue in the [`deno_dom`](https://deno.land/x/deno_dom) library, and it continues to persist (at least as I write this answer — it's at version `0.1.38`).  See the following GitHub issue for more information:

[b-fuze/deno-dom#4 — bug: querySelectorAll returns NodeListOf<Node> instead of NodeListOf<ELement>](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/4#issuecomment-716299531)

That thread contains all of the information and linked resources, but here's the summary:

`deno_dom` doesn't fully or correctly implement the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/), and its types also don't align with the DOM types from TypeScript.

In the TS DOM lib, [the return type of `document.querySelectorAll` is a `NodeListOf<E>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.1.6/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L16741), where `E` is a generic parameter constrained to [`Element`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.1.6/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L7537), which is the interface that implements the [`getAttribute`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.1.6/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L7642) method.

In `deno_dom`, the return type of [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/blob/v0.1.38/src/dom/document.ts#L289) is [`NodeList`](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/blob/v0.1.38/src/dom/node-list.ts#L196-L208), which is an iterable of [`Node`](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/blob/v0.1.38/src/dom/node.ts#L58) (which doesn't include the `getAttribute` method — all `Element`s are `Node`s, but not the other way around).

The actual elements of the `NodeList` are indeed `Element`s, but just aren't typed that way, so — until the library is fixed — you'll have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to inform the compiler of the situation. Here's a self-contained example:

`example.ts`:

```ts
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.193.0/testing/asserts.ts";

import {
  DOMParser,
  type Element,
} from "https://deno.land/x/deno_dom@v0.1.38/deno-dom-wasm.ts";

const html = `
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ice cream flavors</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ice cream</h1>
  <h2>Basic flavors</h2>
  <ul class="flavors basic">
    <li data-flavor="vanilla">Vanilla</li>
    <li data-flavor="chocolate">Chocolate</li>
    <li data-flavor="strawberry">Strawberry</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
`;

const document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
//    ^? const document: HTMLDocument | null
assert(document, "The document could not be parsed");

const flavorElements = document.querySelectorAll(
  "ul.flavors.basic > li",
) as Iterable<Element>; /*
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Use a type assertion here */

const flavors = [...flavorElements].map((element) => {
  const flavor = element.getAttribute("data-flavor");
  //    ^? const flavor: string | null
  assert(flavor, "Flavor attribute not found");
  return flavor;
});

console.log(flavors); // ["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry"]
```

In the terminal:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.35.0 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 11.6.189.7
typescript 5.1.6

% deno run --check example.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/example.ts
[ "vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry" ]
```

For comparison, [here's the equivalent code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#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-ohkpkYAO5Nnc4gCy4hyO5VPEABtIPv0fjjCTgC6QeYyBELg+ATgUUDaP4Z7yIoD4OqOzort+YFBmwtTrlAvAwEcHQYNuzIyqOl6KNeuZ3ooxY4Lgo6JuGcooBhfDYTy7ZwXA4D9pmrwLFAIBYEgo4OI4nF2sOXIYEGPhwGwVFPpmgw5i+uTEmApLkomHJuMKuSJoqupqhqP5yEAA).